# Responsive slides - How to Add button to slides

Tags: jquery, responsive-slides

I am using [responsive slides](http://responsiveslides.com/) for my client project. I need to add a "Read more" button on the slider images with links. I have searched through google and stackoverflow to get an expecting answer. So I have decided to ask a question. Below I have added the code what I have currently done for the slider. I am new to Javascript and JQuery.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="responsiveslides.css"></link>
<div class="rslides_container">
  <ul class="rslides" id="slider">
    <li><img src="1.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="2.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="3.jpg" alt=""></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#slider").responsiveSlides({
            auto: true,
    pager: true,
    pause: true,           // Boolean: Pause on hover, true or false
    pauseControls: true,    // Boolean: Pause when hovering controls
            nav: true,
            speed: 500,
            maxwidth: 800,
    manualControls: "",     // Selector: Declare custom pager navigation
    namespace: "rslides",   // String: Change the default namespace used
    before: function(){},   // Function: Before callback
    after: function(){}     // Function: After callback
        });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey. I think I can help you solve this. Could you provide a few more details please? Preferably a working jsfiddle.net or something? If I see what you have physically someone can help. Or possibly some drawings or a png/jpg that shows what you want exactly...Anything that shows what you have versus what you want would help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9pK9C/4/

Comment: It isnt working in that fiddle. Its got some errors on it when you try to use the "hint" button on fiddle and didnt have a jquery selected. let me know if you fix this and ill try to help friend.

Comment: sorry for the delayed reply. I am having problem with setting the jsfiddle